# Single GCM Push sent to multiple devices with different GCM Id's

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We use GCM messaging to send remote commands to device. We have one particular client who uses the same model of devices from one manufacturer and with has 5.1 OS.
Our client registration process is pretty standard, that is once the client logs-in, it updates the GCM-Id to server and on server we have some commands that can be sent to the registered devices and internally it uses the registration id.
We are observing that even if the remote command is sent to one of the devices, it is being delivered to all these devices. The GCM Id on all these devices is different.
This does not happen with other devices (or we have not seen it yet)
If we use FCM Diagnostics and verify the lifecycle of message using the GCM-Ids of these devices we see that the same message ID has been delivered to all these devices.
We made sure that there is no ghost or random delivery from our backend, we verified backend logs and added extra logging as well.
Request for tips or hints, if anybody else saw such an issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try see this [git](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/gcmsender/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmsender/GcmSender.java) on line 57, he uses json to sent a single message to multiples registration ids.

**Example json content:**

```
{ 
    "data": 
        {
        "from": "my_name",
        "time": "0:56:23"
        },
    "registration_ids": ["id_1", "id_2", "id_3", "id_4"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lucas** is correct in his example, the `registration_ids` is a parameter that specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It can contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

> **Note:** `registration_ids` are only for multicast messaging, not for
>   single recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1
>   registration tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).